# maven install external jar is not functioning properly

Tags: maven, maven-install-plugin

I am new to maven, I want to add commons-codec jar to maven local repository , Actually I want to use this jar in the project but I get compile error which shows the jar could not find at compile-time the project pom file contains

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/commons-codec-1.8.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

and the jar file is in the lib folder in the project root , after some googling I found the I should install the jar by mvn So I execute this

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-2.2.1-bin\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin>mvn install:commons-codec-1.8.jar -Dfile="c:\mapsforge\mapsforge-map\lib\commons-codec-1.8.jar" -DartifactId=commons-codec -Dversion=1.8 -Dpackaging=jar -e
```

and then I get this error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'install'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Required goal not found: install:commons-codec-1.8.jar in org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Required goal not found: install:commons-codec-1.8.jar in org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plu
 gin:2.2 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1867)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.segmentTaskListByAggregationNeeds(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

what's wrong here ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given goal is wrong.

```
mvn install:commons-codec-1.8.jar -Dfile="c:\mapsforge\mapsforge-map\lib\commons-codec-1.8.jar" -DartifactId=commons-codec -Dversion=1.8 -Dpackaging=jar -e
```

it must be:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="c:\mapsforge\mapsforge-map\lib\commons-codec-1.8.jar" -DartifactId=commons-codec -Dversion=1.8 -Dpackaging=jar -e
```

Apart from that i would suggest to use Maven 3.X instead of Maven 2.2.1.